# Invite Twitter friends for app

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, mgtwitterengine

How can we invite our Twitter friends/Followers for any app/Event using my app. For doing the same thing in Facebook I am posting some message to my friends wall. is there any way to do the same thing using MGTwitterEngine.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 4):

go through [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iPhone_iOS_5_TWTeetComposeViewController_Twitter_Application)
and i used Tweet sheet as in [twitter site](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-tweet-sheet)

Comment: This is quit good. Thanks but it won't work in IOS before 5.0. is there any other way by which this can be done in IOS 4.

Comment: opsss... This is for me. it is twitting on my account not to my friends. I want to the same functionality for friends.

Comment: I think you are not getting my question please read it once more.

Comment: yeah i understand your prob, twitter support is for ARC enabled.. but no ARC support in ios 4.1 and earlier..

Comment: @jattt.... have a look @ this discussion https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4874 you can do the same i guess..

Comment: <a href="http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa/" title="MGTwitterEngineTutorial">MGTwitterEngineTutorial</a>

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks !

Comment: @EmptyStack I am sending direct message to my friends for inviting them.

Answer (score 2):

if you have not been through this links then have a glance [Oauth](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/) ,  [Xauth](https://github.com/aral/XAuthTwitterEngine)
 and  [DMTwitterOAuth](http://danielemargutti.com/dmtwitteroauth-ios-twitter-oauth-login-made-easy/#comment-999)

Comment: let me explain this in more detail. I am developing an app and want to send invitation to all my Twitter friends for check the app. invitation may be some text string like "Hey check this awesome app for connecting with your friends.". Same thing I have done in the Facebook using posting on the their wall. some look like Facebook wall posting.